# IndexedDB refusing to delete store when capacity is reached

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have an indexedDB database that is storing a lot of information in separate stores. The chances of it reaching capacity while saving data to a store are high so I need to handle that. I'm successfully capturing the 'QuotaExceededError' onerror and trying to deal with it gracefully. Part of that is to clear and then delete the store itself (part of the app detects the existence of the store to indicate whether or not it is saved in the database... if it exists but holds only some of the information the app won't work as expected, so I need it to either exist and be complete, or not exist at all).

I'm successfully emptying the store but once that's complete and I attempt to delete the store I'm getting a `QuotaExceededError: Failed to OpenBackingStore in database because not enough space for domain` which is the same as the original error I capture, but I've never heard of 'OpenBackingStore' and I don't know how to delete the store.

This is the code I'm using to clear and then delete the store:

```
var db; // when the db is opened it's saved to this global
var db_open; // when the db is opened and saved to the global above, this global boolean is set to true for easy testing. You can safely assume it's true for this example.
var db_version = 0;

delete_active_holding_folder("the_store_name", function() {
    console.log("all done");
});

function delete_active_holding_folder(store_name, _callback) {
    // empty the store
    clearObjectStore(store_name, function() {
        // then destroy it
        destroy_holding_store(store_name, function() {
            _callback("success");
        });
    });
}

function clearObjectStore(store_name, _callback) {
    var store = getObjectStore(store_name, 'readwrite');
    var req = store.clear();
    req.onsuccess = function(evt) {
        console.log("clearObjectStore success");
        _callback();
    };
    req.onerror = function (evt) {
        console.log("clearObjectStore:", evt.target.errorCode);
    };
}

function getObjectStore(store_name, mode) {
    try {
        var tx = db.transaction(store_name, mode);
        return tx.objectStore(store_name);
    }
    catch(evt) {
        return false;
    }
}

function destroy_holding_store(store_name, _callback) {
    if(db_open)
    {
        db.close();
        db_open = false;
    }
    setTimeout(function() { // this allows time for the db to close above
        ++db_version;
        var req = indexedDB.open('holdings', db_version);

        req.onupgradeneeded = function(evt) {
            db = req.result;
            db_open = true;
            db.deleteObjectStore(store_name);
        };

        req.onsuccess = function(evt) {
            console.log("store successfully destroyed");
            db.close();
            db_open = false;
            _callback();
        }

        req.onerror = function(evt) {
            console.log(evt);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

I'm successfully using the `delete_active_holding_folder` function elsewhere without issue, but through a manual 'delete store' facility, rather than off the back of a QuotaExceededError incident. I feel a little out of my depth, any help appreciated!

Comment: Being unable to delete a store due to limited quota seems like a browser-specific edge case and/or bug. What browser are you testing in? It might be appropriate to file a bug against the browser engine.

Comment: @JoshuaBell I'm testing the cordova app on a real iphone 8, so it would be webkit. I would like to test it on the browser version of the app but it's impossible to max out the storage on a laptop, unlike a phone.

Comment: Chrome lets you artificially lower quota using devtools for testing: Application > Storage > Simulate custom storage quota.